# Operator '==' incompatible with operand types 'Boolean?' and 'String'

Tags: asp.net

I was able to use where clause like the first one. But I get an error message when I tried to add "IS_SUBMITTED == FALSE". What do I do? IS_SUBMITTED  is boolean type.

(Working)

```
    dsRequestList.Where = @"REQUEST_DETAIL_TYPE_ID.Contains(""" + RequestID + @""") AND  
APPROVAL_GROUP_ID.Contains(""" + ApprovalID + @""")  AND CREATE_DT >= DateTime.Parse(""" + 
FromDate + @""") AND CREATE_DT <= DateTime.Parse(""" + ToDate + @""")";
```

(Error)
        dsRequestList.Where = @"IS_SUBMITTED == """ + "False" + @""" AND 
    REQUEST_DETAIL_TYPE_ID.Contains(""" + RequestID + @""") AND  APPROVAL_GROUP_ID.Contains(""" 
    + ApprovalID + @""")  AND CREATE_DT >= DateTime.Parse(""" + FromDate + @""") AND CREATE_DT 
    <= DateTime.Parse(""" + ToDate + @""")";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using "=" or "=="?

Also, doesn't this:

```
@"IS_SUBMITTED == """ + "False" + @""" ...
```

evaluate to this:

```
@"IS_SUBMITTED == ""False"" ...
```

i.e. you're actually comparing `IS_SUBMITTED` to the *string* `"False"` instead of `False`.

Comment: I changed as "IS_SUBMITTED == FALSE"

Comment: (I tried this way, but got same error) dsRequestList.Where = @" REQUEST_DETAIL_TYPE_ID.Contains(""" + RequestID + @""") AND APPROVAL_GROUP_ID.Contains(""" + ApprovalID + @""") AND CREATE_DT >= DateTime.Parse(""" + FromDate + @""") AND CREATE_DT <= DateTime.Parse(""" + ToDate + @""") AND IS_SUBMITTED == ""false""";

Comment: That's still comparing `IS_SUBMITTED` with a string. Try ending it with `AND IS_SUBMITTED == FALSE";`.